# How to find the intersection (common elements) between two columns of a single csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, intersection, reader

I am having two columns almost (1000 rows) in a csv file without headers (tab separated). The sample content of the column values are as follows. It can be a phrase or a single word.

CSV File Format:

```
ac           home          

home         big         

new city     city

city         paris

heat         waves

blood        blood pressure

relation     blood
```

Input Format (Edit):

[image]

I want to compute the common elements between two columns of a csv file? Does there exist any way. I absolutely do not have no idea regarding how to achieve this.

I am completely new to file (`.csv`) and its variants. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Output

```
home, city, blood
```

I know how to compute the intersection of two dictionaries, lists etc. But that won't help me to achieve the desired solution.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? Hints: 1/ use the  stdlib's csv module to read your data. CSV is a row-oriented format (one line = one row), so you will have to first loop over the  collect all the data into two distinct sets (the builtin `set` type), one for the first column and one for the second - IOW for each row, you add the first value (first col) to the first set and the second value (second col) to the second set. Then finding the common words is just a matter of doing a set intersection (it's a method of the `set` type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set` --> `set.intersection`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    c1, c2 = set(), set()
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            c1.add(row[0])
            c2.add(row[1])

print(c1.intersection(c2))
```

**Output:**

```
{'home', 'city', 'blood'}
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. It showing `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Do you have empty new line between each row?

Comment: Yes towards last of the column1 a few (10 empty cells).

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: Still `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Looks like some of your rows do not have 2 values.

Comment: By 2 values, did you mean phrase? Yes some have single word and some have phrases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195125/discussion-between-mishra-s-and-rakesh).

Comment: Can you post an exact sample of your input ?

Comment: Done @ rakesh. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Done rakesh. Finally. I have removed the extra spaces from the csv file and then change the delimiter to `,` instead of `\t`. Then it works finally.